# TestMethod do not support Web service callouts, test skipped

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, error-messages

I have written a test class for a trigger on the lead object.

When i run the test class i get the following error:

**Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts, test skipped**

There is an other trigger on lead that has a call to a webservice so i get this error.

I have wrapped the call with:

```
if (!Test.isRunningTest())
{
   // do callout
}
```

But i’m still getting the same error.

Any other way to run correctly the test class?

Thank you.

Comment: All I can think is that there must be another call out occuring in another part of your code. Have you taken a detailed look at the debug log from the test execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm

Note: callout mock type depends by the type of web service that do you have.

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 3):

Saw this on another post, have not tested it.

```
if (!System.Test.isRunningTest()) {
    WebServiceCallout.invoke(...)
} 
else {
  // Simulate callout here...
}
```